# Trying to trace a circular import error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I understand circular import error has been asked about a lot but after going through these questions I haven't been able to solve my issue. When I try to run my server in Django its giving me this error message:

> The included URLconf module 'accounts_app' from path\to\myproject\__init__.py does not appear to have any patterns in it. if you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

The issue started when i added a new app which has a urls.py like the following

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signin$', views.signin, name='signin'),
    url(r'^signout$', views.signout, name='signout'),
    url(r'^signup$', views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

My project urls.py has a line which points to the app and looks like the following code

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts_app')),
]
```

My view looks like the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def signin(request):
    return HttpResponse("<p>This the signin view</p>")

def signout(request):
    return HttpResponse("<p>This the signout view</p>")

def signup(request):
    return HttpResponse("<p>This the signup view</p>")
```

Can anyone please help me identify were I could possibly be going wrong.

Comment: To find the circular dependency just inspect the backtrace.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try changing

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts_app')),
]
```

to

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts_app.urls')), # add .urls after app name
]
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. i couldn't see that error all this time.

Comment: @RahulGupta today it's just like this `url('accounts/', include('accounts_app.urls'))` isn't it?

Comment: You forgot the `r^` before `accounts/`.

Comment: @RahulGupta no i mean when i enter `path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` for example. I get 404 page not found requesting this`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` in the newest django version. But this works `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`

Answer (score 59):

for those who have the same error but still hasn't debugged their code, also check how you typed "urlpatterns"

having it mistyped or with dash/underscore will result to the same error

Comment: thak you very much. missing N in urlpatterns made me lost 5 hours.

Comment: Thank you so much, this took 5 minutes to hunt down thanks to your answer instead of 5 hours!

Comment: or misnaming it urlPatterns instead of all lowercase

Answer (score 8):

Those habitual with CamelCased names may face the error as well.

`urlpatterns` has to be typed exactly as **'urlpatterns'**

This will show you error -

```
urlPatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

**Error -**

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'polls.urls' from '...\\polls\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

**However, fixing the CamelCase will work -**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 8):

After 1 hour search it appears that it's wrong speelling it should be : **urlpatterns**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name="index")
]
```

Comment: Simple as this for me also

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got this error because I called the reverse function for a url that required a slug parameter without placing the correct parameter in it.

Once I fixed the reverse function, it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting error because I was giving wrong path of dir containing urls. So I changed this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/', include('core.urls'))
]
```

to this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/', include('core.urls.api'))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was getting this error because i was typing **urlpatterns** in urls.py  to  **urlpattern**.

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears if SomeView doesn't exist in views.py and you do this:

```
from someapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/someurl/', views.SomeView.as_view(), name="someview"),
]
```

So make sure all Views you use in urls.py exist in views.py

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting

/SLMS_APP1/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

I made a typo in **'urlpatter'**

*urlpatter* = [
path('',views.index, name='index'),

]

where in correct spelling has to be **'urlpatterns'**

*urlpatterns* = [
path('',views.profile, name='profile'),

]

Answer (score 0):

this error basically occurs when you have, include the app in the main urls.py file and haven't declared urlpattern= [] in-app file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed "reverse" for "reverse_lazy" on my success_url and magially it works.

Comment: This is not a solution, but a tricky workaround. I don't think that solving circular import by changing the imported function (reverse and reverse_lazy are not the same) is good solution.

Comment: This works for me, but I agree with you, is not the way to solve a circular import, but in my case, I didn't have any circular import, just changing that, works I was searchig by the error traceback and any of the other anwers work for me, then I realize the problem was related with the URLs, and I just change that and works, if somebody else has the same error and can solve it doing this, great!

Comment: According to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) you should use reverse lazy in specific cases such as providing the URL to a decorator or the URL for a class-based view.  If that's what you were doing then this is the appropriate fix.  Another example in the docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms

Answer (score 0):

I changed this...

```
app_name='users'
urlpatterns=(
    path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(),name='signup')
)
```

to this...

```
app_name='users'
urlpatterns=(
    path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(),name='signup'),
)
```

notice the last **COMMA**