# Problem in Django 2.2 with Debug=True on Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2

I am trying to run a project in Django 2.2 with Debug=True on Ubuntu but I get this error in python manager.py runserver:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'moeaforhdl.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

This is /myparentapp/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('moeaforhdlweb.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is /mychildapp/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^help/$', views.help, name='help')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I test this project on Windows 10 and it works perfectly, but not on Ubuntu.
Besides, if I comment this line:

```
url(r'', include('moeaforhdlweb.urls'))
```

it works.

Any help will be grateful, thanks a lot.

Comment: After looking a bit further into this, I've found this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30500. Can you please verify that there are no improper indentations in the files (most specifically, the `views.py` file)?

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465983/4723929

Comment: Please include the full stack trace

Comment: I included the full stack trace, thanks!