# Django Hello World - does not appear to have any patterns in it - what causes the problem

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm a python dev (among other things), trying to learn Django and I'm already stuck at the hello world. It's tricky cause I'm not quite sure what I'm dealing with at this stage, so maybe you can help me figure it out.

I've got the environment configured via anaconda 2.x, I've tested everything was working until I created the first app. So here are the sources, maybe you can tell what's causing the error.

File structure

[image]

For the project:

settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages_app.apps.PagesAppConfig',

]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages_app/', include('pages_app.urls')),
    
]
```

For the pages_app:

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PagesAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'pages_app'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

url_patterns = [
    path('', views.homePageView, name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def homePageView(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

I'll note that this is my second attempt at hello world app, first one was deleted after I found out name "pages" was taken by a python package in my general_env and I deleted it, all references and created pages_app with the manage.py startapp pages_app command. Before I recreated this renamed app there was already an error, just different.I'm hoping it has nothing to do with other packages otherwise it will be a pain.

Here's my console window log
[image]

I'll be grateful if anyone can help me figure out the problem.
Thanks!

Edit: I've tried setting up a new environment and installing just django, but the problem persists, so it doesn't appear to be a conflict with package names. I've also seen two versions of adding apps urls to project urls

1. `path('', include('pages_app.urls'))`
2. `path('pages_app/', include('pages_app.urls')),`

in both cases I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `url_patterns` variable you defined. Try changing it to `urlpatterns` instead of `url_patterns` under the urls.py of your pages_app.

> Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable
> urlpatterns. This should be a sequence of django.urls.path() and/or
> django.urls.re_path() instances.

Answer (score 0):

After continuous testing different configurations and googling I came by this
[Trying to trace a circular import error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465954/trying-to-trace-a-circular-import-error-in-django)
and I've made the same mistake. I mistyped `urlpatterns` , weirdly enough I was sure that's how the tutorial had it and upon looking it up again, I noticed it's written without the `_`in between.
So there you have it. Sorry for the fuss, I hope it helps someone.